# HTTPWebRequest acts differently from same request sent through browser

Tags: c#, shift4shop

I am working with the shift4shop web api. These guys used to be known as threeDCart if that helps anyone. Its an eCommerce platform.

we are trying to apply a promotion code to an open cart.
support has verified there is no api-way to do that.

there is an url that will apply the promotion. This is often emailed to customers so they can apply the promo if they choose to.
we can paste the correct url in chrome, brave, edge, or firefox and **it correctly applies the promotion.**

We used private tabs  for the different browser tests and the browsers were 'cold'. we launched the browser and immediately entered the URL.
We are thinking this eliminates the possibility that there are cookies that are necessary.

https://www.mywebsite.com/continue_order.asp?orderkey=CDC886A7O4Srgyn278668&ApplyPromo=40pro

However, when I try to do this in C#,  i get a response that is redirected a page that says 'The cart is empty'.
**The promotion is not applied**

I am stumped as to how the website would respond differently to the same URL when it comes from a browser as opposed to the c# system.net library.

here is the c# code I am using

```
using System.Net;

//i really create this using my data, but this is the resulting url 

    string url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/continue_order.asp?orderkey=CDC886A7O4Srgyn278668&ApplyPromo=40pro"
   
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
string result = "";
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You can also call ".view_cart.asp" w the same parameters and the browsers will cause the promo to be applied.

I have tried setting the method to [ , GET, get ]
There has to be something about the request settings that are preventing this from working.

I do not know what else to try.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per shift4shop support, the continue_order.asp has a 302.
the browsers land on continue_order.asp and process that page.
They then continue on to view_order.asp.

The 2 pages together perform functionality that you can not get by just calling continue_order.asp

Thanks to savoy w/ shift4Shop for helping on that.